# A child that commits suicide (R"L) -- losing certain merits

Tags: halacha, minor-katan-child, funeral-burial-levaya, intent-accident-purposely, suicide

A person who kills himself (R"L) as far as I know loses certain zechuyos (merits) in terms of their kavurah (burial) and other dinim (rules. [See here for more](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/16346/what-are-the-halachot-of-suicide)). Is the same true if it was a katan (minor) that committed suicide?

Comment: As the answer to the question you linked to indicates, contemporary practice pretty much universally treats suicides as cases of illness and therefore doesn't treat them differently from other deaths.

Comment: @IssacMoses I linked to it for the sources and realized that would be pointed out. However putting aside the practical aspect what would be the din in the case of a katan.

Comment: @IsaacMoses See the comments on the linked question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Shulchan Aruch (YD 345:3) writes:

> קטן המאבד עצמו לדעת, חשוב כשלא לדעת
>   A minor who knowledgeably destroys himself is considered as if it was not done knowledgeably

so it seems we would treat it like any other regular case of death.